# JPA, Hibernate add mapped class from another jar into persistent context programatically

Tags: hibernate, jpa, entitymanager

I have a modular application, in my core-module i create an instance of entitymanager by calling method `Persistence.createEntitymanager("mypersistenceunitname",myCredentialProperties)`, in other modules i want to be able to define jpa entities.

How can i register a jpa entity, which is not in the same jar as persistence.xml file, to a persistent context? Right now im getting Class not mapped exception if i try to load/save an entity with entitymanager.

I'm aware that i could add an option `<jar-file>pathtojar</jar-file>` into persistence.xml but this would require every time i create a new module edit the xml file. How can i do this programatically?

Im not using Spring, nor jee, its just jse app.